# Unexpected label while trying to iterate over a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am in the process of trying to iterate over a ruby hash. I'll have to admit that my knowledge of ruby is very poor and i am in the process of trying to correct that, and so please bear with me if this is a very elementary question.

I am wondering if the syntax of my hash is off.  The reason why it is looking the way that it is is because it is part of a rakefile, and i need to incorporate multiple addresses in this. (which i've never done, i've always only had 1 address to worry about) I know the solution to this is to build the addresses in as a rakefile, and then loop over them.

```
clinic.build_address.each do | address, value |
                            {
                              (city: "Minneapolis"
                              state: "MN"
                              address1: "316 10th ave"
                              zip: "55414"),
                              (city: "Hudson"
                              state: "WI"
                              address1: "119 Belmont Street"
                              zip: "54016")
                            }
puts build_address
```

With what I have right now I am getting an unexpected label (it is not liking that I have 'city:minneapolis')

Would anybody be able to take a quick look at what I have with this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Right now, you loop over `clinic.build_address` and then are building what looks a bit like a hash for each element there. The syntax is not valid though and it is not clear, what this should achieve. Please edit your question and add your intentions: what exactly do you want to do with your data?

Comment: Hey thank you so much for taking a look at this.  This is part of a rakefile which is how the syntax originally was.  Basically what I am trying to do is loop through both of these and then list them.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Right now you iterate over build address, do something really weird with parenthesis inside a... hash? Then throw away all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If your `Clinic` model has an `Address` model related, and you run `build_address`, you won't end up with a hash, but an ActiveRecord object.  However, I'm not sure what exactly your goal is.</strike>

To iterate a hash, you would use:

```
some_hash.each do |key, value|
   # some logic using key and/or value
end
```

Maybe you mean you want something like this:

```
addresses = [
  {
    city: "Minneapolis"
    state: "MN"
    address1: "316 10th ave"
    zip: "55414"
  },
  {
    city: "Hudson"
    state: "WI"
    address1: "119 Belmont Street"
    zip: "54016"
  }
]

addresses.each { |a| clinic.build_address a }
```

Comment: hm....ok. I looked into possibly going down this road, 
    build_address.each do | state, value |
                                {
                                  (state: "MA"),
                                  (state: "NY")
                                }
However i am getting snagged right at the first state.

Comment: Can you post the original rake task you're trying to alter, so I can explain what it's doing and possibly guide you to some understanding? As it is, your syntax just doesn't make sense. (No offense intended, it's just wrong and I don't understand what your expectation is.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I know I was not the clearest with what I was looking for, but with your help, I was able to work my way through it!

Comment: I'm glad to help.  

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to do but your code is not a valid Ruby code. The closest I could get to is this:

```
{a: "b"}.each do | address, value |
  [
    {
      city: "Minneapolis",
      state: "MN",
      address1: "316 10th ave",
      zip: "55414"
    },
    {
      city: "Hudson",
      state: "WI",
      address1: "119 Belmont Street",
      zip: "54016"
    }
  ]
end
```